# windows application setup problem?

Tags: c#, winforms

I developed a window application and setup for that application, when i click the setup it is open and when i clicked for second and third time and so on it is opening again and again.
please help me in this situation thank u.

I developed the application in C# language.it is running perfectly but when i click the setup again it is opening how can i stop it?

Comment: with this much information, you might not get an answer. Atleast not the right one :)

Comment: What exactly do you want?  For the application not to run multiple times if clicked multiple times?  Do you want it to detect that setup is already running?... Please be more clear

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is pretty much the expected behaviour. If you want to make sure that only one instance of your programm is started - which can be pretty challengeing - this is another issue. Pls let us know which language etc. you're using.

[This codeguru article](http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/w-p/system/sharedmemory/article.php/c10799/) might be a good starting point anyways.

ADDITION:

In C# terms you might find [this devblogpost](http://www.pixvillage.com/blogs/devblog/archive/2005/04/21/218.aspx) interesting.